# Commas with possessive nouns?

Tags: grammar

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this question but I'm wondering which is correct, or if someone can suggest an alternative to me, that would be great too.

> The difficult nature of client Anna's case required him to....

> The difficult nature of client, Anna's, case required him to...

I feel like neither are right but can't seem to find any answers on this.

Comment: Has Anna been mentioned before? If her name is being introduced for the first time, I would put it between commas to indicate that that is the name of the client in question. (_His client_ or _the client, Anna_ would be better.)

Comment: His client, Anna, had a case of a very difficult nature; this required him to...